# Cannot programmatically "check" a radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons, and would like to make both the button itself and the attached text be clickable (to improve usability).

This should be very straightforward, but for some reason the radio button's state will not update when triggered from jQuery. What happens is the `checked` attribute will appear in the DOM, but the radio button seems to remain unchecked (visually).

Note: It works perfectly when I run the code from the console, but when it's triggered normally by my function, it does not update. Also, this code works perfectly for *un-checking* the other radio buttons in the group... so I'm confused as to why it doesn't work in the other direction.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="radio-input">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_category" id="cat_standard">
    <span class="inline-label">Standard</span>
</div>
<div class="radio-input">
    <input type="radio" name="ad_category" id="cat_reward">
    <span class="inline-label">Reward</span>
</div>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(".radio-input").click( function() {

  if (!$(this).children("input:radio").attr("checked")) {

    $(this).siblings(".radio-input").children("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");

    $(this).children("input:radio").attr("checked","checked");

  }
});
```

For the record, calling `click()` on the element produces the same non-result, even though it works fine when triggered from the console. Also, both `.prop` and `.attr` yield the same result (working in console, not working in regular flow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="ad_category"> Standard</label>
```

That's what the `<label>` tag is for, after all...

Anyway, to answer the actual question, there is a difference between the `checked` *attribute* and the `checked` *property*. An example of this difference would be a text field: `input.value` is the current value, and `input.getAttribute("value")` holds the default value.

Comment: ... I wasn't aware that this functionality was baked into <label>. This solved the problem immediately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To attach the label's click to a radio, you can do it two different ways:

```
1. stick the radio inside the label tags
```

or

```
2. use a for="" attribute in the label, in which the value is equal to the ID of the radio


    <label for="x">something</label>
    <input id="x" type="text" value="my field" />
```

Then check if the field has attribute `checked="checked"`

Comment: #2 is the preferred method from the a11y point of view: [WCAG 2: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the case in the DIV work, maybe because you have things other than the label in a panel to click on, the following should work to select the radio.  I think the issue in your example was the conditional logic - this shouldn't be needed as Radios cannot be unchecked, and therefore you do not need to worry about the current state.  If checked, it will stay checked.  Also, youy do not need to handle the siblings, as that should be taken care of for you by the browser (at least it works in Firefox).

```
$('.radio-input').click(function () {
  $(this).children('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Note that this does not fire the change event, only sets the specific radio to checked, and as mentioned, the browser will uncheck the currently selected radio.